# "Top" and "Bottom" don't work in @media

Tags: html, css

I've tried to make adaptive design of site for iPad. So, i have a problem with left-sidebar and top-nav. Between it and header have a little gap.
I had wanted to fix it using "top" in @media, but this function doesn't work.

In common style this function works great.
So,if anybody can, please write me what mistake I made

[image]

```css
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
    .topnav {
        top: 50%;
    }
    
    aside {
        min-width: 17%;
        min-height: 100%;
        bottom: 30px;
    }
}


aside { /*Sidebar*/
    padding: 5% 0.5%;
    margin: 0% auto;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    float:left;
    list-style-type: none;
    width:15%; 
    background-image: url(images/side.PNG);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    background-size: 75%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 10%;
    z-index: -2;
}

aside li {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial , "sans-serif", helvetica;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 140px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 15px;
    
}


.topnav {
    margin:6.2%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.5%;
    top: 0%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: red;
    text-align:center;
    z-index: 2;
    
}

/* Navigation links */
.topnav a {
    margin:0 auto;
    display:inline;
    margin-left:3px;
    line-height: 12px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 700;
    float:left;
    font-family: verdana, "sans-serif", helvetica, arial;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>    
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title>Новости - Анонсы</title>
    </head>
<body>
     <header>
    <img src="images/headerfinal.png" class="Header" alt="Header">
    </header>
    <nav>
    <div class="topnav"> <!--Верхнее меню -->
  <a href="#top">Новости</a>
  <a href="#top">О Суде</a>
  <a href="#top">Решения КС РФ</a>
  <a href="#top">Заседания КС РФ</a>
  <a href="#top">Контакты</a>
    </div>
    </nav>
    
    <section> <!-- Основной текст -->
<h3 class="News">Новости - Анонсы</h3>
<br>
<br>
<p>10 ноября 2017 года Конституционный Суд РФ провозгласит Постановление по делу о проверке конституционности Федерального закона «О внесении изменений в отдельные законодательные акты РФ в части совершенствования законодательства о публичных мероприятиях»</p>
<br>
<p>( <a href="#top">подробнее...</a>)</p>
<br>
<p>7 ноября 2017 года Конституционный Суд РФ провозгласил Постановление по делу о проверке конституционности ряда положений Закона Республики Крым «Об особенностях регулирования имущественных и земельных отношений на территории Республики Крым»</p>
<br>
<p>( <a href="#top">подробнее...</a>)</p>

<br>
    <a href="#top">Посмотреть все новости</a>
<br>
    </section>
    <aside> <!-- Меню слева -->
<ul>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<li><a href="#top">Новости</a></li>
<li><a href="#top">О Суде</a></li>
<li><a href="#top">Решения КС РФ</a></li>
<li><a href="#top">Заседания КС РФ</a></li>
<li><a href="#top">Контакты</a></li>
</ul>
<br>
<img src="images/gerb.gif" alt="Герб РФ" align=center>
    </aside>
<br>
<br>
    <footer>
        <hr style="border:1px; height:1px; width: 70%; margin-left: 270px; background-color:black">
    <img src="images/footer.PNG" class=footerline alt="Footer">
        <a href="index.html">©Конституционный Суд Российской Федерации, 2008-2017</a>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to cancel the top in your media query for the aside (`top:auto`), but not sure why your topnav top doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

Media queries have no influence over specificity. The normal rules of the cascade apply.

Both your rulesets have the same selector (`.topnav`), so they are equally specific. The means that rules are applied **in order**.

First `top` is set to `50%;`, then the second rule sets it to `top: 0%;`.

Change the order of your rules.